# vuex dispatch action with params but got null params value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to create action in my vuex , that action has method to `goLogin` with parameter the object of *email and password*, in this case I am using **Nuxt**, when I try to use fetch in my component, the ***dispatch*** work well with that *params*, but when I try to move it as method for **@click**, the *dispatch params* is null thought I console log inside the action method, it was not null, but when it hit to back end API, back end API read it as null

here is my action:
in store/login.js

```js
export const actions = {
  goLogin({ commit }, obj) {
    // I console.log the obj here, it was not null
    return LoginService.tryLogin(obj).then((res) => {
      commit("IS_LOGIN", res.data);
    }).catch(e => {
      commit("IS_LOGIN", e.response.data);
    })
  }
}
```

the LoginService got it from instance axios, it is like this

```js
tryLogin(obj) {
  // I console.log the obj here, it was not null
  return goAxios.get("/login", {
    data : obj,
  })
}
```

in my component method for @click login

```js
async tryLoginFromComponent() {
  await this.$store.dispatch("login/goLogin",{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
  })
},
```

when I click login, the methop of `tryLoginFromComponent` run and it going to action in store/login.js
but the obj of that params null in back end, thought I console.log was not ,

is that something wrong with I did above ?? I have tried to search all day but can't found any work for me , I hope everybody here will save my time what's going there

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab of the developer tools? Is the request correct at that point and, if not, how does it differ from what it should be?

Comment: Using `data` with a `GET` request is unlikely to be what you want. Either it should be a `POST` or that should be `params` instead of `data`.

Comment: @skirtle on the network it was nothing on the body data, it was correct to hit the api,  do u usually `POST` for login ??

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a `GET` request for login, not least because it has side-effects. But the key point here is that you're using axios incorrectly. Passing a `data` option to the `get` method won't do anything. If the server is using a `GET` request then you'll need to use `params` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to call `tryLoginFromComponent` asynchronously because `actions` are already asynchronously. Maybe there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tryLoginFromComponent() {
    this.$store.dispatch("goLogin",{
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "12345678",
    })
  },
```

No need to put email and password in double quotes here. That's an object not a JSON key-value-pair. Try that.